# ZF2 exception handler suppreses PHP parse errors

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

When producing a parse error, e.g. inside a Controller, ZF2 exception handler catches it and I only see

```
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
No exception available
```

If I produce a parse error inside `public/index.php` I can see the plain PHP error in the browser, so PHP settings are correct.

How do I force ZF2 to show errors like this in dev mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I was using an old version of `view/error/index.phtml` (part of skeleton app) which was not prepared for errors of type Error (since PHP 7) and only handled errors of type Exception.

Had to change this line

```
<?php if(isset($this->exception) && $this->exception instanceof Exception): ?>
```

to this

```
<?php if (isset($this->exception) && ($this->exception instanceof \Exception || $this->exception instanceof \Error)) : ?>
```

Comment: since both Exception and Error class implements \Throwable, don't you think that's better to test the interface instead ?

Comment: @Hooli That’s a valid suggestion! The current [Zend Skeleton Application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/view/error/index.phtml#L6) explicitly checks for \Error and \Exception. However, it doesn’t look like they’re using any methods not defined in \Throwable.